# regex: replace within repeating group, sublime text

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext

How can I replace all of `\\` with `/` in a string starting with `C:\\Code`?

- Input:

  - `C:\\Code\\foo\\bar\\baz bla blah`
- Output:

  - `/user/local/code/foo/bar/baz bla blah`

I have this regular expression already, which matches what I want:

```
C:\\\\Code(?:\\\\[^(\\\\|\s)]+)*
```

However, when replacing it, I am having trouble because nothing gets saved for access through `$1` in the replace string.

If I used this

```
C:\\\\Code(\\\\[^(\\\\|\s)]+)*
```

I only have access to the very last match (in this case `baz`), and `foo` and `bar` are missed out.

Comment: It there a reasonable limit to the number of parts in the paths?

Comment: @Bohemian yeah safe to say it won't exceed ten

Comment: Another question - would a command line solution be ok?

Comment: @Bohemian yeah, command line is good too - `sed` preferred!

Answer (score 0):

Are 2 substitutions acceptable ?. It would still achieve your goal in sublime text.

If so then you can get out of regex mode and swith to normal mode.

First substitution `C:\\Code\\` with `/usr/local/code/` Second substitution`\\` with `/`

Comment: Yes, 2 are OK, althought I would prefer 1. However, your answer is not OK in this case, because I only want to replace `\\` when it is is in this string that starts with `C:\\Code\\`

Comment: Then Wouldn't it be asking too much from a regex, because we want to conditionally replace something based on some other charecter? Just my opinion. Your requirement can be easily fulfilled by a script in perl/python.

Comment: Actually, regular expressions excel at matching strings based on multiple conditions. For example, take the one in my question. What I am having trouble with here is ensuring that the match stores the *capturing groups* correctly.